# Is Drupal CMS or CMF?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

Can you explain me what is Drupal? CMS or CMF?

Googling about differences CMS and CMF I understood that there are Frameworks, CMF and CMS. Using Framework I can create CMF and CMS, using CMF I can create CMS. CMF is just platform based on Framework (or not) that includes some basic stuff like app structure, authorization and so..

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drupal is both according to Wikipedia:

[CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system):

> A content management system (CMS) is a computer program that
>   allows publishing, editing and modifying content on a web site as well
>   as maintenance from a central page.

[CMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_frameworks):

> A content management framework (CMF) is a system that facilitates the
>   use of reusable components or customized software for managing web
>   content.

And without further argument, I guess its safe to say that Drupal fits into both of the above definitions.

Comment: Ok, so Yii is CMF also because it facilitates the use of reusable components? Fails to meet in the head, sory)

Comment: I guess my point is that it is -kind of- a subjective question. It might be easier to answer if you tell us why this is important, or in which context it matters. Without that, my answer is one correct answer, but might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience of Drupal 6, I would say it's a "CMS++" : you have all the usual CMS functionality (Documents, Rules, Workflows, User management, templating, etc).
And its design has  been refined over the years to make it very very extensible. So any  time you need extra functionality and someone hasn't already written it for you, you can write some PHP yourself and hook into extension points. There's no hacking involved.

Theoretically, there's nothing preventing you from using Drupal as a CMF and just writing a bunch of extensions. But I would say that if your site is not content-orentied, it's probably overkill.